# How to manage several projects with git

Tags: android, git, git-submodules, project-organization, git-subtree

I want to organize all my java, C and Android projects with Git.

I have several folders:

```
something_like_gdlib
example_library1
example_library2
...
example_project1
example_project2
...
```

In each of those projects I use some of those libraries. But if I update a library, I want all projects to get the changes for that library.

Usually I work alone on those projects and I just want to have a change history.

Now I want to work together with another programmer, that should get access to only one project and the corresponding libraries.

How should I set up git? I heard of subtrees or submodules? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submodules or subtrees could indeed be a solution.

On the other hand you could keep the repos totally independent from a git point of view, and publish your libraries.

Eg: Assuming you're working with Maven in Java, when you want to upgrade `example_library1` in `example_project1` you could:

- Build a new version of the library (and tag the corresponding commit)
- Put this binary either in a local or shared maven repository
- Update the version of the library in the `pom.xml` of your project

An advantage of this approach would be that there are no need to do anything complicated with Git

Drawbacks would be:

- It may be cumbersome if you want to upgrade in your application every time you commit in your library
- If you don't already have a "package architecture", you may need to set it up first